# How to change cursor image in Python

Tags: python, winapi, win32gui, win32con

I want to change my cursor image (everywhere on screen) when my program is running.

I try to load image with win32gui and then use win32api to change cursor image, but something is wrong and my cursor doesn't show up
My cursor image is map.cur

```
import win32api
import time
import win32gui
import win32con

x = win32gui.LoadImage(0,'map.cur',win32con.IMAGE_CURSOR,0,0,win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)
win32api.SetCursor(x)

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Have you check the return value of functions? If `x` is a valid `HCURSOR` and if  SetCursor() execute successfully?

Comment: You're going to have to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor) more carefully. Particular points of interest: *"The cursor is a shared resource. A window should set the cursor shape only when the cursor is in its client area or when the window is capturing mouse input. [...] If your application must set the cursor while it is in a window, make sure the class cursor for the specified window's class is set to NULL. If the class cursor is not NULL, the system restores the class cursor each time the mouse is moved."*

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT
I think it is valid 'HCURSOR' and it executes successfully because when I run my program cursor changes for like 0.1s but then changes back to my windows cursor.

Comment: @IInspectable
Sorry, I'm pretty new into programming and don't understand what should I do exactly.
If I'm not wrong I can change cursor only in my program window? And when I try to go outside my window it will always change back to OEM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the system cursor is not recommended, because the cursor has to be restored after program exits, and if the program fails then user is stuck with custom cursor and must reset the cursor from system settings.

For the sake of curiosity, it can be done with `SetSystemCursor`, example

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SetSystemCursor(hcursor, 32512) #OCR_NORMAL
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsystemcursor) for `OCR_NORMAL` and other cursor constants.

You can try to save the old cursor and restore it, again, this method fails if your program exits abnormally.

```
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui
import ctypes
import time
import atexit

#save system cursor, before changing it
cursor = win32gui.LoadImage(0, 32512, win32con.IMAGE_CURSOR, 
                            0, 0, win32con.LR_SHARED)
save_system_cursor = ctypes.windll.user32.CopyImage(cursor, win32con.IMAGE_CURSOR, 
                            0, 0, win32con.LR_COPYFROMRESOURCE)

def restore_cursor():
    #restore the old cursor
    print("restore_cursor");
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetSystemCursor(save_system_cursor, 32512)
    ctypes.windll.user32.DestroyCursor(save_system_cursor);

#Make sure cursor is restored at the end
atexit.register(restore_cursor)

#change system cursor
cursor = win32gui.LoadImage(0, "file.cur", win32con.IMAGE_CURSOR, 
                            0, 0, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE);
ctypes.windll.user32.SetSystemCursor(cursor, 32512)
ctypes.windll.user32.DestroyCursor(cursor);

time.sleep(3)
exit
```

Comment: @Lxix69 check this out

Comment: `hcursor` is defined nowhere so this doesn't work for me, can you tell me how to do this ?

Comment: It worked with me; I had to install "win32api" package; but I was not able to restore the default system cursor; any idea how we can do that?

Comment: @Rida Did you make sure `hold` and `hsave` are saved before changing the cursor? It works for me on Windows 10, I don't know if you implemented the code exactly as shown above.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani
I think i stopped the python script mistakenly before it gets the chance to restore the default cursor ..

Comment: do u have any idea how to fix that programmatically in such situation?

Comment: @RidaShamasneh You can use atexit or another method to make sure it's called at the end. But again that's going to fail if system terminates the program prematurely. Updated answer.