# How can I change system mouse cursor in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, ctypes, mouse-cursor

I'm making a Tkinter program where the user can capture an image from the screen through mouse dragging.

When program is running, I want to change the mouse cursor to cross type.
I looked up how I can do it, but I could only find codes that change the cursor type when it is only inside the `Tk` window.
I wish the cursor to be cross type wherever it is, even when it's outside of `Tk` window.

I also tried,

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SetSystemCursor(hcur, 32515)
```

but it gets an error saying 'hcur' is not defined.

What should I do?

Comment: You can get a handle to the current cursor with `hcur = ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursor()`. You could also try `ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorInfo()`. That said, I haven't had much luck with either...further digging required! There may be some useful information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/cursors)

Comment: @JRiggles Worked! I didn't know I had to declare hcur first. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! And just to clarify, you can use any name you like - it doesn't *have* to be `hcur`, so long as you refer to the same variable name where needed. E.g.: `banana = ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursor(); ctypes.windll.user32.SetSystemCursor(banana, 32515)` :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change cursor image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55954005/how-to-change-cursor-image-in-python)